# How to debug with `nodemon` in nuclide? The breakpoint doesn't hit

Tags: javascript, node.js, atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I'm a JS noob looking for some help:-) I'm trying to learn nuclide's debugger follow the official doc. The source code is from [flow's five examples'](https://github.com/facebook/flow/tree/master/examples) `hello.js`.

I started with executing the following command:
`nodemon ./01_HelloWorld/hello.js --exec babel-node`

Then I successfully attached the debugger to this process. The console also printed 
`Starting debugger agent.
Debugger listening on 127.0.0.1:5858`

I added a breakpoint on the 4th line `return x*10`. However, no matter what I do the program just doesn't hit the breakpoint.

I know that in google dev tools the program will hit breakpoints after `refresh`. How can I do something similar to `refresh`? Would you please tell me what's the next step should I do? Many thanks!